# How to connect to redis with class

Tags: php, redis

In my project, I have defined two classes  Datasource and RedisHelper in Datasource.php file.

Datasource is for getting data from redis.

RedisHelper is for connecting redis.

Here is code of Datasource.php:

```
<?php

namespace common;

class Datasource {

public static $redises = array();
public function __construct() {}

public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {
    global $config;
    $redis_config = $config['redis'][$config_name];
    try {
        self::$redises[$config_name] = RedisHelper::instance($config_name, $redis_config, $server_region);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        self::$redises[$config_name] = null;
    }
    return self::$redises[$config_name];
}
}

class RedisHelper {
private $_config_name = "";
private $_redis_config = null;
private $_server_region = null;
public $timeout = 1;
private $_redis = null;
private static $instances = array();
private static $connect_error = 0;
private $call_error = 0;

private function __construct($config_name, $redis_config, $server_region) {
    if ($config_name && $redis_config && $server_region) {
        $this->_config_name = $config_name;
        $this->_redis_config = $redis_config;
        $this->_server_region = $server_region;
        $this->timeout = isset($this->_redis_config[$server_region]['timeout']) ? $this->_redis_config[$server_region]['timeout'] : $this->timeout;
        try {
            $this->_redis = new \redis();
            $this->_redis->connect($this->_redis_config[$server_region]['host'], $this->_redis_config[$server_region]['port'], $this->timeout);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_redis = null;
        }
    } else {
        $this->_redis = null;
    }
}

public static function instance($config_name, $redis_config, $server_region) {
    if (!$config_name || !$redis_config) {
        return false;
    }

    $only_key = $config_name . ':' . $server_region;
    if (!isset(self::$instances[$only_key])) {
        try {
            self::$instances[$only_key] = new RedisHelper($config_name, $redis_config, $server_region);
            self::$connect_error = 0;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (self::$connect_error < 2) {
                self::$connect_error += 1;
                return RedisHelper::instance($config_name, $redis_config, $server_region);
            } else {
                self::$connect_error = 0;
                self::$instances[$only_key] = new RedisHelper(false, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
    $redis_config_info = array();
    if ($redis_config && isset($redis_config[$server_region]) && isset($redis_config[$server_region]['password'])) {
        $redis_config_info = $redis_config[$server_region];
        unset($redis_config_info['password']);
    }

    self::$connect_error = 0;
    return self::$instances[$only_key];
}

}
```

Here is redis.ini.php file:

```
<?php
 $config['redis']['instance1'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
 )
);
$config['redis']['instance2'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
  )
 );
```

Now I want to connect redis with classes, Here is my html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" >
<div><h3>haha</h3></div>
<?php 
   include "o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource.php";
    include 'o1ws1v/conf/redis.ini.php';
   $redis_obj = common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');
$value = $redis_obj->get("xie");
echo "get key xie is:".$value."\n";
?>
</body>
```

But It works fail. $redis_obj is nothing in my console. Who can help me?

Comment: You cannot just print an object to your display.  It is complex data, not a simple string.  Try changing the last echo line to wrap your `$redis_obj` in [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).  It will probably give you a bit more insight.

Comment: @Bing, see my update